# Xpt 2046 Display with Pn532 RFID reader

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, spi, rfid, lcd

I have an 3.5 inch XPT 2046 Display on my Raspberry Pi 3, and i am trying to make it work with an PN532 RFID Reader. I can run each one standing alone, but together the display wont work. Display is connected via SPI Gpio Pins and RFID is connected via I2C Pins. Both is enabled in the Configuration on the Raspi. I cant figure out how to make it work and i have no Ideas why it wont work. Drivers are up to date.

I tried to edit the Config.txt, the driver options, googled for that specific topic but it seems like no one has ever stumbled across my explicit Problem.